# How do I make blogger homepage full width and hide sidebar?

Tags: html, blogs, blogger, homescreen, blogspot

I am using blogger and want to hide the side bar from my blog homepage to make the posts full width and look more customized/proffesional, my website is [nijeva.ca](http://nijeva.ca) and I am using a custom theme template that isn't one of bloggers defaults.

I have attempted to use a code before  but it always says you cannot place a `b:if` code there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to “Template” > “Edit HTML“
Click inside the HTML editor

Use `CTRL+F` to find the second `<head/>` in your blog’s HTML

Past the given code Above it.
This for Home page

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <style>
        .sidebar {
            display:none;
        }
        #main-wrapper {
            width: 99%; 
            float: none; 
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
        html {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        } 
        .post {
            width: 97%; 
            margin: 15px auto;
            } 
        .post h3 a { 
            text-align: center; 
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
</b:if>
```

And this  for Static Page

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType ==  &quot;static_page&quot;
'<style>
    .sidebar {
        display:none;
    }
    #main-wrapper {
        width: 99%; 
        float: none; 
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .post {
        width: 97%; 
        margin: 15px auto;
    } 
    .post h3 a { 
        text-align: center; 
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
</b:if>
```